# Calling a function pointer inside the same class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I almost but not quite implemented function pointers inside my class to avoid the duplication of code of a large loop.

```
class Scanner
{

    void GenerateTextureMap();
    void OtherOuterWork();

    /* 
        Extracting the triangle sweep for loop (that is repeated code for each time we need to sweep the triangles) 
        Of note:
            - "How can I avoid syntax errors when creating pointers to members? Use a typedef" https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#typedef-for-ptr-to-memfn
            - "How can I avoid syntax errors when calling a member function using a pointer-to-member-function? use std::invoke (C++17)" https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#macro-for-ptr-to-memfn 
    */
    typedef  int (Scanner::*TriangleSweepFunction)(int triangleIndex, Vec2D texv0p, Vec2D texv1p, Vec2D texv2p);
    void TriangleSweep(TriangleSweepFunction p);

    void MatchCameraToTrianglePaintTextureTriangle(int triangleIndex, Vec2D texv0p, Vec2D texv1p, Vec2D texv2p);
    void OtherInnerWork(int triangleIndex, Vec2D texv0p, Vec2D texv1p, Vec2D texv2p);

}

void Scanner::TriangleSweep(TriangleSweepFunction p)
{
    for (int triangleIndex = 0; triangleIndex < m_mesh.m_triangles.size(); triangleIndex++)
    {
        // ...
        // loads of code
        // ...

        std::invoke(p, this, triangleIndex, texv0p, texv1p, texv2p);
    }
}

void Scanner::MatchCameraToTrianglePaintTextureTriangle(int triangleIndex, Vec2D texv0p, Vec2D texv1p, Vec2D texv2p)
{
    // Inner work on Scanner object variables
    // ...
}

void Scanner::GenerateTextureMap()
{       
    TriangleSweep(&Scanner::MatchCameraToTrianglePaintTextureTriangle);
}
```

`TriangleSweep(&Scanner::MatchCameraToTrianglePaintTextureTriangle);`

yields

`E0167  argument of type "void (Scanner::*)(int triangleIndex, Vec2D texv0p, Vec2D texv1p, Vec2D texv2p)" is incompatible with parameter of type "Scanner::TriangleSweepFunction"`

`Error C2664 'void Scanner::TriangleSweep(Scanner::TriangleSweepFunction)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__cdecl Scanner::* )(int,Vec2D,Vec2D,Vec2D)' to 'Scanner::TriangleSweepFunction'`

and

```
    TriangleSweepFunction p = &Scanner::MatchCameraToTrianglePaintTextureTriangle;
    TriangleSweep(p);
```

yields

`E0144  a value of type "void (Scanner::*)(int triangleIndex, Vec2D texv0p, Vec2D texv1p, Vec2D texv2p)" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Scanner::TriangleSweepFunction"`

**What's the proper syntax here?** (taking advantage of the typedef already defined)

Comment: The return types are different. It looks like `TriangleSweepFunction` should have a `void` return type instead of `int`. Edit : Voting to close for being a typo.

Comment: `typedef  int (Scanner::*TriangleSweepFunction)(int triangleIndex, Vec2D texv0p, Vec2D texv1p, Vec2D texv2p);`  What do you think the `Scanner::` here does?

Comment: @UKMonkey: OP wants to use pointers to members function, so OP use correct syntax for typedef.

Comment: Note that type alias are a lot friendlier for naming function and member pointer types. For example : `using TriangleSweepFunction = void (Scanner::*)(int, Vec2D, Vec2D, Vec2D);`. The name of the type is right there at the start and everything after the `=` is type related information. `typedef` hides the name in the middle somewhere, it can be hard to spot. You also don't need to *name* the parameters in a function pointer type, which can improve the clarity of the definition. Though one could argue that providing names helps document what each parameter means. So it's up to you.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, txs, that's it.

Comment: @Jarod42 Since the typedef is already within the Scanner class; the 2nd scanner is not required at all.  It's a bit like typing `class X{ int X::foo(); }`

Comment: @UKMonkey: So you miss the difference between `using func = void (*)();`(pointer on function(so only for free function or static method)) and `using func = void (SomeClass::*)();` (pointer on **member** function (for non static methods of class `SomeClass`)).

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I do/did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typo:

`typedef  int (Scanner::` should be  `typedef  void (Scanner::` since my functions return void (`void MatchCameraToTrianglePaintTextureTriangle(` `void OtherInnerWork(`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, you're creating a function pointer , not a pointer to int when you do (note there is no need for Scanner:: scope operator inside class definition) :

```
typedef int (Scanner::*TriangleSweepFunction)(int triangleIndex, Vec2D texv0p, Vec2D texv1p, Vec2D texv2p); void TriangleSweep(TriangleSweepFunction p);
```

You need to do:

```
typedef int * TriangleSweepFunction (int triangleIndex, Vec2D texv0p, Vec2D texv1p, Vec2D texv2p); void TriangleSweep(TriangleSweepFunction p);
```

//function returns int pointer

```
int * fun ( int, int);
```

//Creates a function pointer to a
//function type that returns int!

```
int (* fun) (int , int);
```

**Note: The parentheses around function
 name really matters when you create a function pointer**

Comment: OP creates and want to create pointer on **member** function, not regular pointer function, so `Scanner::` is required.